# Subgroups of every order dividing the order of the group imply the group is abelian?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group, denote $|G|=n$.

I know about Cauchy theorem which states that if for a prime $p$:
$p|n$ then there is $H\leq G$ with $|H|=p$.

I also know that an abelian group $G$ have a subgroup of every order
dividing $n$.

This leads me to the following two questions:

1. Is the more general statement that $m|n\implies\exists H\leq G$
   with $|H|=m$ true ?
2. Assuming that indeed there is a subgroup of every order dividing
   $n$, can I conclude $G$ is abelian ?

Comment: No, you can't conclude that. Take for example any finite **non-abelian**  $\;p$- group

Comment: @Timbuc - I see your point. But this seems to answer only (2), can you also give an example for (1) ? thanks!

Comment: The alternating group $\;A_4\;,\;\;|A_4|=12\;$ doesn't have a subgroup of order six...so it also isn't true.

Comment: The nonabelian group of order $21$ has subgroups of order $1,3,7,21$ - and a similar thing is true of every nonabelian group of order $pq$ where $p$ and $q$ are both prime.

Comment: $S_3$ is a counter example. Evidently for all divisors of $6$ there exists a subgroup of those orders.

Comment: Every nipotent group has this property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, no. In fact, it's even worse! The quaternion group $Q_8$ has subgroups of all possible orders, and every subgroup is *normal*, but the group isn't abelian!

More generally $p$-groups, groups whose orders are a power of a prime, will have subgroups of all orders, yet need not be abelian.

There is a partial converse to Lagrange's theorem, about orders of subgroups we are guaranteed to find, but you'll have to wait for Sylow theory.  You'll see that if $p^k$ divides the order of a group, where $p$ is prime, then the group has a subgroup of order $p^k$. It's the only theorem of its type I know, but that doesn't mean there aren't others.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Can you please rephrase or explain the theorem you are taking about "if divides the order of a group with a prime, then the group has a subgroup of order " it seems to be missing a word or two and it sounds like Cauchy theorem..

Comment: @Belgi Yeah, the wording was a bit clunky there; I tried to improve it. [Sylow's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylow_theorems) says that if we have a group $G$ of order $p^nm$, where $p$ is prime and $p\nmid m$, then $G$ has a subgroup of order $p^n$. We can then conclude it must have a subgroup of order $p^{n - 1}$, which in turn has a subgroup of order $p^{n - 2}$, etc, applying Sylow's theorem to smaller and smaller subgroups of $G$.